# EditText mask with 3 decimal places in java [android]

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, masking, textwatcher

i'm newbie in Android and i want to do a mask for an EditText with a decimal number with 3 decimal places(ex: 0.658), i need a mask that user doesn't need write the ".", only the numbers, like a conventional mask for currency.

I'm trying create a TextWatcher based in this:

```
public static TextWatcher currency(final EditText editText) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        String current = "";

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().equals(current)) {
                editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                String cleanString = s.toString();

                if(count != 0) {
                    String substr = cleanString.substring(cleanString.length() - 2);

                    if (substr.contains(".") || substr.contains(",")) {
                        cleanString += "0";
                    }
                }

                cleanString = cleanString.replaceAll("[R$,.]", "");

                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
                String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format((parsed / 100));
                formatted = formatted.replaceAll("[R$]", "");

                current = formatted;
                editText.setText(formatted);
                editText.setSelection(formatted.length());

                editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    };
}
```

But without success.

There are a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText) from github.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. So I started looking for any implementation of TextWatcher. I finally decided to build my own:

```
public class BrRealMoneyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private static final Locale DEFAULT_LOCALE = new Locale("pt", "BR");

    private static DecimalFormat NUMBER_FORMAT = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(DEFAULT_LOCALE);

    private static final int FRACTION_DIGITS = 2;

    private static final String DECIMAL_SEPARATOR;

    private static final String CURRENCY_SIMBOL;

    static {
        NUMBER_FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(FRACTION_DIGITS);
        NUMBER_FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(FRACTION_DIGITS);
        NUMBER_FORMAT.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = String.valueOf(NUMBER_FORMAT.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator());
        CURRENCY_SIMBOL = NUMBER_FORMAT.getCurrency().getSymbol(DEFAULT_LOCALE);
    }

    final EditText target;

    public BrRealMoneyTextWatcher(EditText target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    private boolean updating = false;

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int after) {
        if (updating) {
            updating = false;
            return;
        }

        updating = true;
        try {
            String valueStr = formatNumber(fixDecimal(s.toString()));
            BigDecimal parsedValue = ((BigDecimal) NUMBER_FORMAT.parse(valueStr));
            String value = NUMBER_FORMAT.format(parsedValue);
            target.setText(value);
            target.setSelection(value.length());
        } catch (ParseException | NumberFormatException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Erro ao aplicar a máscara", ex);
        }
    }

    private String formatNumber(String originalNumber) {
        String number = originalNumber.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
        switch(number.length()) {
            case 0 :
                number = "0" + DECIMAL_SEPARATOR + "00";
                break;
            case 1 :
                number = "0" + DECIMAL_SEPARATOR + "0" + number;
                break;
            case 2 :
                number = "0" + DECIMAL_SEPARATOR + number;
                break;
            default:
                number =  number.substring(0, number.length() - 2) + DECIMAL_SEPARATOR + number.substring(number.length() - 2);
                break;
        }
        return CURRENCY_SIMBOL + number;
    }

    private String fixDecimal(String number) {
        int dotPos = number.indexOf('.') + 1;
        int length = number.length();
        return (length - dotPos < FRACTION_DIGITS) ? fixDecimal(number + "0") : number;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
}
```

I hope it helps somebody else.